# Unity can't find any Rigidbody

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to learn Unity and I'm following a tutorial on YouTube. I made a script for the player movement and I have to attach it to a RigidBody2D but Unity can't find any Rigidbody, even if I actually created it.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTRX5.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with your script is that it asks for a `RigidBody`, not a `RigidBody2D`. Changing the variable type in your script from `RigidBody` to `RigidBody2D` should let you be able to drag it in.

Answer (score 1):

You created RigidBody2D in your player but you never assigned it to your script.
Your script should be like this if you want to skip that step:

```
public class PlayerMovement
{
    RigidBody2D rigidBody;

    Awake()
    {
        rigidBody = GetComponent<RigidBody2D>();
    }
}
```

If you want to do it manually, you should just drag the RigidBody2D component to the empty RigidBody2D field.

Comment: Even better to use [OnValidate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnValidate.html).

Comment: What is need for OnValidate? You just assign RigidBody2D once. OnValidate's purpose is when a variable value change, validate it and do the necessary operations accroidng to changes.

Comment: Sure, you can do a lot more with `OnValidate`. I think the real advantage of using `OnValidate` over `Awake` for finding components becomes apparent when you have a lot of references to set and when they are required in editor mode.

Comment: I get it why you suggested. But OnValidate will work in build too. Clearly OP is beginner so, it is unnecessary for him/her. But thanks for pointing out again.